# What is this type of parameter called in LLVM?

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-ir

I want to write an LLVM pass to modify the "fpga.scalar.interface" in the following LLVM IR below:

```
define void @_Z6ssFunciiPi(i32 "fpga.scalar.interface"="ap_hs" %arg_in0, i32 "fpga.scalar.interface"="ap_hs" %arg_in1, i32* "fpga.scalar.interface"="ap_hs" %arg_out0) #0 !dbg !7 {
```

I am not sure what "fpga.scalar.interface" is called in LLVM... Is it metadata, or an attribute? And where I can find documentation about it so I can modify these in my code, e.g. add/change/remove.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are [parameter attributes](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#parameter-attributes). You can create them using [this constructor](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Attribute.html#a3469e685d3fadac587ccaa4ca8144d70).

Comment: Thanks! This is really helpful!